# Find number of functions such that $f(f(a))=a$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Let X ={1, 2, 3, 4}. Find the number of functions $f : X \rightarrow X$ satisfying $f(f(a)) = a$ for all $1 \le a \le 4$.

I took the $f(x) =x$ and, then there are 1 possibilities. But answer is given as 10. How is it 10?

Comment: Think about swaps.  Functions that will have this property might do something like $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$ (swaps) so that $f(f(a))=f(b)=a$.  So each element is either "swapped with itself" or swapped with another element.

Comment: Just as a curiosity: If we consider this problem for arbitrary $n$ instead of just $n=4$, then we get [telephone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_%28mathematics%29). (At least that is what Wikipedia calls them.) See also [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html) and [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000085).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple more possibilities.  See if you can figure out the remaining.

$1\to 2, 2\to 1, 3\to 3, 4\to 4$

and

$1\to 2, 2\to 1, 3\to 4, 4\to 3$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $f(x)=x$, then of course we’ll have $f(f(x))=x$ as well, but there’s another possibility: if $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x$, then $f(f(x))=f(y)=x$ and $f(f(y))=f(x)=y$, so both $x$ and $y$ behave correctly. These are the only possibilities, however. Let’s give each such function a code describing which elements of $X$ it leaves fixed and which elements it swaps: if $f(x)=x$, we’ll write $(x)$, and if $f(x)=y\ne x$ and $f(y)=x$, we’ll write $(xy)$. The code for the identity function is therefore $(1)(2)(3)(4)$. The code for the function that sends $1$ to itself, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $2$ and $4$ to itself is $(1)(23)(4)$.

Now the question becomes: How many such codes are there?

- We can have $0$ swaps; that’s $(1)(2)(3)(4)$, the identity function.
- We can have $1$ swap and two fixed points, like $(1)(23)(4)$; how many of those are there?
- We can have $2$ swaps, like $(13)(24)$; how many of those are there?

Comment: can you tell me complete solution to this problem?

Comment: @mathophile: With elementary problems like this I prefer to leave at least a little work for the reader, but I’ll extend the hint a bit. Notice that for the type with one swap, the function is completely determined once you’ve chosen the two members of $X$ to be swapped; how many ways are there to choose two members of $X$? And for the type with two swaps, note that once you know which of the numbers $2,3$, and $4$ is swapped with $1$, you know the entire function.

Comment: This is what i obtained $f(1)=1,f(2)=2, f(3)=3, f(4)=4 $$\implies$ one function $\;$ Now function with $1$ swap $ {4 \choose 2} \cdot =6$ and function with $2$ swaps ${4 \choose 2} \cdot {2 \choose 2} =6$ so there are total $13$ such function. Am i correct?

Comment: @mathophile: You’re right about the number with one swap, but you’ve overcounted the functions with two swaps. Such a function has to swap $1$ with either $2,3$, or $4$. Say it swaps $1$ and $3$; then it *must* swap $2$ and $4$, so there’s only one $2$-swap function that swaps $1$ and $3$, the function represented by $(13)(24)$. Your calculation counts this function twice, once for the $(13)$ swap and once for the $(24)$ swap. Similarly, there’s only one $2$-swap function that swaps $1$ and $2$, and only one that swaps $1$ and $4$, and you’ve counted each of these functions twice.

Comment: Thanks. Where to find such kind of problem more?. And is there any generalization method for such problem? For example let's take $f(f(f(x)))=x$, $\;$ $f:A\rightarrow A$ where $A={1,2,3,4,5}$

Comment: @mathophile: You’re welcome. I’m afraid that I really don’t know of any source for problems of this general kind. I’ve not thought about this sort of thing in years, but I’d attack your example in a similar fashion: if $f:A\to A$ is a bijection such that $f(f(f(x)))=x$ for each $x\in A$, it’s not hard to show that $f$ divides $A$ into singletons $\{a\}$ such that $f(a)=a$ and triplets $\{a,b,c\}$ such that $f(a)=b$, $f(b)=c$, and $f(c)=a$. Then it’s a matter of calculating the number of such decompositions of $A$.

Comment: I've given thought to your comments. And this is what i deducted **Case 1** $f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(3)=3,f(4)=4,f(5)=5$ $\implies$ $1$ such function. **Case 2** select any three elements out of five elements from set $A$ i.e. ${{2,4,5}}$ and corresponding function will be $f(2)=4,f(4)=5, f(5)=2, f(1)=1, f(3)=3$ and $f(2)=5, f(5)=4, f(4)=5, f(1)=1, f(3)=3$ So there total $1+ {5\choose 3} \cdot 2 =21$ function. Am I correct?

Comment: @mathophile: Yes, that’s correct.